# Can you give a column a standard value?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to put the value '0' in the database without having to fill in a text field.

Is there any way to give a column the value '0', when i save a form in the database?
This is the form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $base_url; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table class="sug" width="300">

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" required></td>

            <td><input type="text" name="level" placeholder="Level"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea placeholder="Beschrijving" name="beschrijving" maxlength="200"></textarea></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="file" name="afbeelding" required id="afbeelding"></td></tr>


        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Toevoegen"/>
            </td></tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

The save function:

```
  if (!empty($post_array)) {
// Check the add form:
$add = FALSE;

if (isset($post_array['add'])) {
    // Save images
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["afbeelding"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Upload afbeelding
    $projecten->upload($_FILES['afbeelding']);


    // Save project
    $result = $projecten->save($post_array);
    if ($result) {
        // Save was succesfull
        $add = TRUE;
    } else {
        // Indicate error
        $error = TRUE;
    }
}
} 


  public function save($input_array) {
    global $wpdb;

  // Insert query
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $wpdb->prefix . "ivs_canvas_tabel` 
        ( `naam`, `level`, `beschrijving`, `afbeelding`)" .
                    " VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", $input_array['naam'], $input_array['level'], $input_array['beschrijving'], $_FILES['afbeelding']['name']));

  // Error ? It's in there:
    if (!empty($wpdb->last_error)) {
        $this->last_error = $wpdb->last_error;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I have no idea how to add the field, i hope someone can help me out!

Yours sincerely

Comment: Keep default to mysql column as "0".

Comment: Either add to db the default value of colum zero or just add it directly to the query: `INSERT INTO ivs_canvas_tabel (colom, naam, level, beschrijving, afbeelding) VALUES ( 0, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');`

Comment: i dont want to do it directly because i have two forms in the same database. one form i wil give value 1 and the other form value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using input with hidden attribute in form:

```
<input type=“hidden” name=“colom” value=“0” />
```

Comment: To hide the element you set it's atribute to `type="hidden"` [Element/input/hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). And you have weird quotes in the answer. Check: `"` != `”`.

Comment: i have tried this but then wit value="1". when i add a new one it doens't change the value in 1 in the database it stays empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can put default value in your database:

```
alter table `table_name`
modify column `column_name` int default 0;
```